# How to insert entries in a related model with a corresponding condition met from the parent table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

SO I have a tablr `users` table whose structure is

> id | name  | email | password | role_id

and it has 100 entries in it.

I have a `couriers` table whose structure is

> id | user_id | so on.

I would like to populate the `couriers` table with the value in the `users` table that has the role_id of 3.

So I have 40 couriers and I want them to be inserted into the `couriers` table.

Comment: you want to populate the couriers table with the proper `user_id` ? what if there is more than one user with `role_id` equal to 3

Comment: Yeah. That is why the below's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO couriers (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM users
WHERE condition;
```